# Basic Authentication Using Message Handlers In Web API send username and password in data boject

Tags: c#

When consume web Api first check username and password and validate then go according controller and action method

so actual i want to make generalized method before hit controller validated user

Comment: You have to add more information. Which framework are you using? And very important: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Action filters:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, 
IAuthenticationFilter
{
  public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
  {            
  }

  public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
  {            
  }
}
```

[Full Tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters)

Comment: thank u but actually when anonymous   send post request for specific controller like Home/User +Data{fristname: "",lastname:""} then if its validate user then proceed

Comment: Yes, this kind of handing is possible in the above code.